# Solr Facets - Newbie - Can I have the JSON response for facets to include both key and value?

Tags: solr

I am experimenting with Solr Facets. I imported my DB

pseudo:

```
item   colorName  colorID
ball   red        1
plate  red        1
table  blue       2
```

Now, when I display the facet on the site, I instinctually want to have both colorName and colorID in my json, however the Solr Fusion interface and all the documents I have read the last several hours tell me I can only do either {Colorname, count}  or {colorID, count}  where I actually want { colorID,ColorName, count}. I dont have a real reason actually but coming from the old times, I couldn't feel comfortable with just a name or id and not both...

Answer (score 0):

Facets are meant to be simple `key => value` pairs, with the key being your `facet.field` and the value being the number of documents that fall under that facet. The idea is to be able to give users a broad overview of various categories, along with the number of items available in that category. From there, you can use filter queries to drill down further into the data.

Your best bet in your example is to facet on multiple fields. For example:

`/select?q=field_name%3APIN&rows=0&wt=json&indent=true&facet=true&facet.field=unique&facet.field=manufacturer_id`

And then filter on whatever combination you need.

Comment: yeah, I ended up making multiple facet queries and then merging the returned arrays for display